# Ms Excel combine data from 2 table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've 2 sets of data, A and B as shown below.

[image]

What I want to do is to combine data A and B to produce data C.

Is there a way to automate this instead of manual copy and paste?

What is the best solution to do this as the actual data is huge.

Comment: If you are expecting IP to repeat 3 times then Policy & Description will be repeated also the expected out put is an odd combination,, you may refer [my post](https://superuser.com/questions/1535933/ms-excel-copy-and-paste-data-multiply-by-x/1535975#1535975)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in a module and linked to a button on the page, it assumes your IP addresses are in A, Policy in C and description in D. Output goes to columns F,G and H.

```
Sub matrix()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheet1
Dim MyIPRnge As Range, MyPRnge As Range, MyDRnge As Range
Dim MyX As String
Dim MyArr() As Variant
Dim i As Long, x As Long, y As Long, MyCols As Long

Set MyIPRnge = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 1), ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 1))
Set MyPRnge = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 3), ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells(2, 3).End(xlDown).Row, 3))
Set MyDRnge = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 4), ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells(2, 4).End(xlDown).Row, 4))
MyCols = ws1.Cells(2, 3).End(xlToRight).Column - 2 ' the two assumes it is in column 3 to start with, modify to 1 less than start col
ReDim MyArr(MyIPRnge.Rows.Count * MyPRnge.Rows.Count)
x = 1
For i = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr) - 1
    MyArr(i) = MyPRnge(x, 1)
    If x = MyPRnge.Rows.Count Then
    x = 1
    Else
    x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 7), ws1.Cells((MyIPRnge.Rows.Count * MyPRnge.Rows.Count) + 1, 8)) = Application.Transpose(MyArr)
x = 1
For i = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr) - 1
    MyArr(i) = MyDRnge(x, 1)
    If x = MyDRnge.Rows.Count Then
    x = 1
    Else
    x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 8), ws1.Cells((MyIPRnge.Rows.Count * MyPRnge.Rows.Count) + 1, 8)) = Application.Transpose(MyArr)
ReDim MyArr(MyIPRnge.Rows.Count)
MyArr = MyIPRnge.Value2
y = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(MyArr) * MyPRnge.Rows.Count Step UBound(MyArr)
    For x = 1 To UBound(MyArr)
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(x + i, 6), ws1.Cells(UBound(MyArr) + i, 6)) = MyArr(y, 1)
    Next x
    y = y + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to combine the data from `Data B` with every row from `Data A`

The code below assumes:

- Data A is a `Table` on `Sheet1` named `DataA` and has a single column.
- Data B is a `Table` on `Sheet1` named `DataB` and can have multiple columns.
- The Output is going on the same worksheet, but you can easily alter the code to put it elsewhere.

If the data is not in tables, you can easily use a different algorithm to find them.

Since the code does the "work" in VBA arrays, dictionary and collection, if your data is sizeable, you should see a noticeable speed difference compared with read/writing to/from the worksheet.

The code should auto-adjust if you add more rows to either table, or more columns to `DataB`

```
Option Explicit
Sub combineTables()
    Dim loA As ListObject, loB As ListObject
    Dim dataA As Variant, dataB As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, V, W, X
    Dim myD As Dictionary, Col As Collection
    Dim sKey As String

    Dim vRes As Variant, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range

'Read the data into variant arrays for processing speed
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'or whatever

Set loA = ws.ListObjects("DataA")
Set loB = ws.ListObjects("DataB")

dataA = loA.DataBodyRange
dataB = loB.DataBodyRange

'Write the combinations into a dictionary to organize it
Set myD = New Dictionary

For I = 1 To UBound(dataA)
    Set Col = New Collection
    sKey = dataA(I, 1)
    myD.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=Col
        For J = 1 To UBound(dataB)
            ReDim V(1 To UBound(dataB, 2))
            For K = 1 To UBound(V)
                V(K) = dataB(J, K)
            Next K
            myD(sKey).Add V
        Next J
Next I

'Output the results into an array
ReDim vRes(0 To UBound(dataA) * UBound(dataB), 1 To UBound(dataA, 2) + UBound(dataB, 2))

vRes(0, 1) = "IP"

For J = 1 To loB.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count
    vRes(0, J + 1) = loB.HeaderRowRange.Columns(J).Value
Next J

I = 0
For Each V In myD.Keys
    For Each W In myD(V)
        J = 1
        I = I + 1
        vRes(I, J) = V
        For Each X In W
            J = J + 1
            vRes(I, J) = X
        Next X
    Next W
Next V

'write to the worksheet
Set wsRes = ws
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 10)
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]