# Ms Excel copy and paste data duplicate by x

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've `Data A` table in Microsoft Excel.

What I want to do is to copy the content in that data and paste it multiply by X.

Let say X is 3.

The actual X number is huge, so automation is really needed here instead of copy and paste it hundreds times.

[image]

Comment: this is duplication, not multiplication

Comment: Hi @user11392987 ,, check my post below I've solved the issue☺

Answer (score 2):

*Few helper value along with `INDIRECT` worksheet function solves the issue:*

**Situation 1:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put desire value in cell `G2`, indicates that how may times you want to repeat set of data.
- Row counter formula in cell `G3`:

`=COUNTA(F2:F4)*G2`

- Final formula in cell `H2`:

  ```
  =IF(ROW(H2)>G$3+1,"",IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("F"&ROW(F2))),INDIRECT("H"&(ROWS($F$2:F2)-(COUNTA(F:F)-2))),F2))
  ```

**N.B.**

- Fill formula down till few extra rows.

---

**Situation 2:**

[image]

**N.B.**

- *As soon you change value in cell `G2`, to repeat set of data `n times`, the formula will adjust result in `column H`.*
- *You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code. Link to a button on the page, it assumes input is from A2 down and output will go from C2 down on sheet1 (change to suit).

```
Sub Duplicate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
Dim MyCRnge As Range, c As Range
Dim MyX As String
Dim MyArr() As Variant
Dim i As Long, x As Long

Set MyCRnge = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row, 1))

MyX = InputBox("Give me a number", "My Duplicator")
If Not IsNumeric(MyX) Then Exit Sub
MyX = CLng(MyX)

ReDim MyArr(MyX * MyCRnge.Rows.Count)
x = 1
For i = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr) - 1

    MyArr(i) = MyCRnge(x, 1)
    If x = MyCRnge.Rows.Count Then
    x = 1
    Else
    x = x + 1
    End If

Next i

ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 3), ws.Cells((MyX * MyCRnge.Rows.Count) + 1, 3)) = Application.Transpose(MyArr)

End Sub
```

Comment: I just updated this so that the x value would adapt to the size of your range rather than stuck on 3, sorry I missed it the first time I posted.